# Enforce single figure to be placed in its specific section, while figures in other sections unrestricted

Tags: graphics, floats, sectioning, positioning

I want to have a figure placed inside its designated section, so I read about it here: [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211078/enforce-figures-to-be-placed-in-the-same-section)

But, the problem with using `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` is that it will cause all other sections to be restricted to its command, while I only need one section applying this package and figures in other sections unrestricted. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use the `[section]` argument so by default nothing happens, then put `\FloatBarrier` at the point that you want to stop the float.

Comment: @Hans I can not understand your comment at all. This answer does exactly what you ask. The effect of `[section]` is to add `\FloatBarrier` to every section, and you asked that it just affected one section, and this does exactly that. As your question has no example not really sure what else anyone could offer as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward tip David. This is also a relevant post you have contributed to : [strange figure floats](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98988/strange-figure-floats)